# 'MainPage' is a type but is used like a variable

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im creating a mobile app with Xamarin.Forms in VS 2022 and it just throws the error from the title at me and I can't find any alternatives to navigation or fixes for this on Google.

Code-behind:

```cs
private void Button_Clicked(object sender)
{
    string username = txtUsername.Text;
    string password = txtPassword.Text;

    if (username == "username" && password == "password")
    {
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
    }
    else
    {
        DisplayAlert("Invalid username or password", "Please Try Again", "Ok");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```xml
<StackLayout>
    <Frame BackgroundColor="LightSkyBlue" Padding="12" CornerRadius="0">
        <Label Text="Login Now" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
    </Frame>
    <Frame Margin="30,0,20,0" CornerRadius="35">
        <Entry x:Name="txtUsername" Placeholder="Id Number"/>
    </Frame>
    <Frame Margin="30,0,20,20" CornerRadius="35">
        <Entry x:Name="txtPassword"  Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"/>
    </Frame>
    <Button Text="Login" CornerRadius="30" Margin="60,10,60,0" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

I just wanted to navigate through my pages `MainPage` to `HomePage`. I've tried using `PushAsync()` but it's not compatible with Android.

Comment: This is not related to Android. The `MainPage` property belongs to the `App` class and is not available in your `MainPage` class. You're mixing up the type and the property, which is why you see that error. In order to use `PushAsync()`, you need a `NavigationPage` object as described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#performing-navigation). Jason's answer should solve your problems.

Answer (score 1):

`MainPage` is a property of the `App` object.  If you want to assign it from a normal page, try this

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
```

from that point on, you should be able to do navigation using `Navigation.PushAsync(...)`

Comment: Maybe show how this applies to the OP's specific problem, both with setting the `MainPage` or by navigating with `PushAsync()`. Just an idea.